# JHipster/Spring Prod Startup Silent Failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I built my JHipster 5.7.0 app with **mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests**, which passed successfully. However, when starting up with java -jar my_app.war --spring.profiles.active=prod, I only get this far, with no errors reported.

```
JHIPSTER LOGO
:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::
```

In application-prod.yml, it doesn't matter if I set spring -> profiles -> active: prod.

Any ideas on what causes silent Spring/JHipster startup failures?

Comment: Is the database up and connectable?  If SQL, also make sure it's not currently locked - check the `databasechangeloglock` table

Comment: Yes it was up and connectable. I ended up just blowing away the prod yml file, copying over the UAT one, and swapping out the details. Now I'm working, although a silent failure from the config really shouldn't be silent.